# Get data from OMDb API with xml

Tags: php, ajax, api

I'l try to get the movie title and info from the omdb API. This is my code:

```
<?php
$enter = $_GET["enter"];
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=$enter&r=xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

if($xml) {

echo "<h2>" .$xml->title. "</h2>";

 }
else
{
echo "Nothing found. Add the info manualy";
}
?>
```

The "enter" value is from the search form with AJAX. He create only an empty h2 tag. How can i get also the data from the API?

Thank you,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with the structure of the xml to know how to access its elements. `print_r(get_object_vars($xml))` will show you a structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [totalResults] => 3651
            [response] => True
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => World War Z
                            [year] => 2013
                            [imdbID] => tt0816711
                            [type] => movie
                            [poster] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg0NTgxMjIxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDM0MDY1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Captain America: Civil War
                            [year] => 2016
                            [imdbID] => tt3498820
                            [type] => movie
                            [poster] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ0MTgyNjAxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjUzMDkyODE@._V1_SX300.jpg
                        )

                )

            ...
            ...
            ...  

            [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => War
                            [year] => 2007
                            [imdbID] => tt0499556
                            [type] => movie
                            [poster] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzNTA4MTc3OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTA0ODk0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So you receive an array with results where you need to pick from. Alternatively if you know the exact title the API has the `t=title` option which only returns a single result (see [documentation](http://www.omdbapi.com/)).

So assuming you use the `s=title` option which returns multiple results, you can use something like this to pick information from the first result:

```
<?php
$enter = $_GET["enter"];
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=$enter&r=xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

# show the structure of the xml
# print_r(get_object_vars($xml));

if($xml) {
    print "<h2>" .$xml->result[0]['title']. "</h2>";
    print "<br>imdbID=" . $xml->result[0]['imdbID'] ;
} else {
    echo "Nothing found. Add the info manualy";
}
?>
```